# Golang processing images via multipart and streaming to Azure

Tags: azure, go, image-uploading, azure-blob-storage

In the process of learning golang, I'm trying to write a web app with multiple image upload functionality.

I'm using Azure Blob Storage to store images, but I am having trouble streaming the images from the multipart request to Blob Storage.

Here's the handler I've written so far:

```
func (imgc *ImageController) UploadInstanceImageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
reader, err := r.MultipartReader()

if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

for {
    part, partErr := reader.NextPart()

    // No more parts to process
    if partErr == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    // if part.FileName() is empty, skip this iteration.
    if part.FileName() == "" {
        continue
    }

    // Check file type
    if part.Header["Content-Type"][0] != "image/jpeg" {
        fmt.Printf("\nNot image/jpeg!")
        break
    }

    var read uint64
    fileName := uuid.NewV4().String() + ".jpg"
    buffer := make([]byte, 100000000)

    // Get Size
    for {
        cBytes, err := part.Read(buffer)

        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Printf("\nLast buffer read!")
            break
        }

        read = read + uint64(cBytes)
    }

    stream := bytes.NewReader(buffer[0:read])
    err = imgc.blobClient.CreateBlockBlobFromReader(imgc.imageContainer, fileName, read, stream, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        break
    }
}

w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
```

}

In the process of my research, I've read through using r.FormFile, ParseMultipartForm, but decided on trying to learn how to use MultiPartReader.

I was able to upload an image to the golang backend and save the file to my machine using MultiPartReader.

At the moment, I'm able to upload files to Azure but they end up being corrupted. The file sizes seem on point but clearly something is not working.

Am I misunderstanding how to create a io.Reader for CreateBlockBlobFromReader?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

As @Mark said, you can use [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://godoc.org/io/ioutil#ReadAll) to read the content into a byte array, the code like below.

```
import (
   "bytes"
   "io/ioutil"
)

partBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(part)
size := uint64(len(partBytes))
blob := bytes.NewReader(partBytes)
err := blobClient.CreateBlockBlobFromReader(container, fileName, size, blob, nil)
```

According to the godoc for [`CreateBlockBlobFromReader`](https://godoc.org/github.com/curoverse/azure-sdk-for-go/storage#BlobStorageClient.CreateBlockBlobFromReader), as below.

> The API **rejects** requests with **size > 64 MiB** (but this limit is not checked by the SDK). To write a larger blob, use [CreateBlockBlob](https://godoc.org/github.com/curoverse/azure-sdk-for-go/storage#BlobStorageClient.CreateBlockBlob), PutBlock, and PutBlockList.

So if the size is larger than 64MB, the code shoule be like below.

```
import "encoding/base64"

const BLOB_LENGTH_LIMITS uint64 = 64 * 1024 * 1024

partBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(part)
size := uint64(len(partBytes))
if size <= BLOB_LENGTH_LIMITS {
   blob := bytes.NewReader(partBytes)
   err := blobClient.CreateBlockBlobFromReader(container, fileName, size, blob, nil)
} else {
   // Create an empty blob
   blobClient.CreateBlockBlob(container, fileName)
   // Create a block list, and upload each block
   length := size / BLOB_LENGTH_LIMITS
   if length%limits != 0 {
       length = length + 1
   }
   blocks := make([]Block, length)
   for i := uint64(0); i < length; i++ {
        start := i * BLOB_LENGTH_LIMITS
        end := (i+1) * BLOB_LENGTH_LIMITS
        if end > size {
            end = size
        }
        chunk := partBytes[start: end]
        blockId := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(chunk)
        block := Block{blockId, storage.BlockStatusCommitted}
        blocks[i] = block
        err = blobClient.PutBlock(container, fileName, blockID, chunk)
        if err != nil {
        .......
        }
   }
   err = blobClient.PutBlockList(container, fileName, blocks)
   if err != nil {
      .......
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Peter, do you know why CreateBlockBlobFromReader requires the size up front, alongside the reader?

Comment: @Mark Azure Storage SDK for Golang or other languages is wrappered Storage REST APIs. The [`Put Blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-blob)/[`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-block) require `Content-Length` header in the rest request.

Answer (score 0):

A [Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) can return both an io.EOF and a valid final bytes read, it looks like the final bytes (cBytes) is not added to `read` total bytes. Also, careful: if an error is returned by `part.Read(buffer)` other than io.EOF, the read loop might not exit. Consider [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) instead.

CreateBlockBlobFromReader takes a Reader, and part is a Reader, so you may be able to pass the part in directly.

You may also want to consider Azure block size limits might be smaller than the image, see [Asure blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs).

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for answering. I was trying to see if I could pass in part directly to CreateBlockBlobFromReader, but I get an error from Azure saying that the body length is 0 and therefore there is a mismatch with the Content-Length (what I pass in as 'read'). Do you know why that is? I'll try passing in part directly again.

Comment: Andrew see Peter's helpful answer above.